# Lloyd's algorithm run within an arbitrary polygon, to spread points evenly throughout polygon.

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Can Lloyd's Algorithm be used to spread points evenly inside of a user selected arbitrary polygon? Or can it only be done in simple polygons, such as a hexagon? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: What a coincidence. I was just researching smarter solutions than the one given in gis.SE over 2 years ago: [qgis 3 - Insert n points equally distributed into many polygons - Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333709/insert-n-points-equally-distributed-into-many-polygons)

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone I checked the the top answer, but those points didn't look evenly spread from each other? Can Lloyd's Algorithm be run within that polygon, with the sides of the polygon serving as boundaries to the cells if they come in contact, and be used to spread the points evenly relative to each other? By Lloyd's Algorithm, I mean as defined in http://www.bitbanging.space/posts/lloyds-algorithm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm. Thank you.

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone Question, why are the lines split where they are? By what metric did you choose the location of each partition?

Comment: That answer over at gis.SE is a naive approach. Polygons in a Geographical Information Systems have a well-defined start vertex (that coincides with the end vertex). The perimeter is divided by n-1 and the boundary of the polygon is split into n parts of equal length, starting at the start vertex (probably going [counter-clockwise](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/147971/122597)).

I was hoping to find a smarter solution in this math.SE post that truly spreads points evenly. I'm adding a bounty

Comment: Oh wow, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I'll bite.  What does "truly spreads points evenly" mean?  There are at least half a dozen ways that might be defined.

Comment: For the sake of discussion, here is the Wikipedia article on [Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm).  The algorithm itself has been discussed [here previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348506/lloyds-algorithm-in-normed-vector-spaces).

Comment: @hardmath Evenly spread means that all points are of approximately equal distance from each other. In this case, it's evenly spreading them inside of any type of polygon, and if we're considering the example provided by Stefan_Fairphone, possibly having holes.

Comment: @hardmath No, I was just clarifying what evenly spread meant in the context of this question.

Comment: @hardmath http://www.bitbanging.space/posts/lloyds-algorithm this is what I'm basing this on. It's not perfect, but it's as evenly as possible.